# Django Nested Query in Template

Tags: django

Loan Model:

```
class Loan(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Member, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

Loan Pay Model:

```
class LoanPay(models.Model):
    loan = models.ForeignKey(Loan, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

want to show data like the image
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iypUb.png)

How to make nested loop in template or any better idea in views

Comment: Use related managers like `Loan.objects.first().loanpay_set.all()`

Comment: Can you show me an example.

Comment: `object_list = Loan.objects.all()` `for obj in object_list:` `for loanpay in obj.loanpay_set.all()` `print(loanpay.amount)`

Comment: Its not sum total amount, It shows separated data